# How to configure SAML2 authentication for a loopbackJS application

Tags: passport.js, loopbackjs, saml-2.0, passport-saml

I would like to secure a loopback based app using SAML2.0 and [OneLogin](https://www.onelogin.com/connector/guardian%20anytime). I believe I should use the `loopback-component-passport` and `passport-saml` modules in order to achieve my goal. However I'm really struggling to find any good documentation that could help me to implement my use case. Seems like the [provided sample](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport) is outdated and not so accurate. Would you have any useful pointers or advice that'd help me to get started.

Thanks

Comment: so did you figure it out ? I'd also need some help ..

Answer (score 2):

SAML authentication in Loopback is poorly documented, but supported.  Reading the source code of [passport-configurator](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport/blob/256c05518cd7167cf4604277f9a3aa58dbf4fda1/lib/passport-configurator.js#L195) tells us that the following configuration of `providers.json` will work:

```json
"saml": {
    "name": "saml",
    "authScheme" : "saml",
    "module": "passport-saml",
    "callbackURL": "",
    "entryPoint": "",
    "issuer": "",
    "audience": "",
    "certPath": "",
    "privateCertPath": "",
    "decryptionPvkPath": "",
    ...
}
```

Here the ellipsis indicates any additional options from the [passport-saml](https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml) provider.  Note that no special processing is performed on these options; so, for instance, you will need to pass `certPath`, `privateCertPath`, etc. as strings rather than paths to files.

See how passport is configured using these properties [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport/blob/256c05518cd7167cf4604277f9a3aa58dbf4fda1/lib/passport-configurator.js#L483).

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't think there is a clear explanation in Loopback's docs about this, so what I would do is try to figure out how to configure the SAML provider in the prviders.json correctly in order to generate the right passport auth strategy (In your case, you should follow the passport-saml docs to figure out the exact parameters you need to pass).

Loopback is using the loopback-component-passport module to read the provider and create the Passport strategies. You can dig into [this file](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-passport/blob/master/lib/passport-configurator.js#L395) to figure out how exactly they are doing it.